# Can't run strapi and react concurrently

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, strapi, concurrently

I was truing to run strapi and react in strapi's public directory concurrently but having problems.

```
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! errno 1
[1] npm ERR! public@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR!
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the public@0.1.0 start script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1]
[1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[1] npm ERR!     C:\Users\---\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-20T09_22_38_328Z-debug.log
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! errno 1
[1] npm ERR! react-strapi@0.1.0 client: `npm start --prefix public`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR!
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the react-strapi@0.1.0 client script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1]
[1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[1] npm ERR!     C:\Users\---\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-20T09_22_38_408Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your Strapi app and react-app seperate to each other? If so, there shouldn't be an issue with starting your React app **that is not related to Strapi**, as Strapi should essentially be your backend while your React-app is front-end. Can your React app run separately fine?

Comment: No, I just want to run react and strapi in same terminal with concurrently but not running

Comment: You should have them separate, as React app should make calls to your backend Strapi app. If both project are in the same folder that's fine as long as **they are both separated ** into their own folders (client & server) and each run on it's own. You can still run them concurrently; you navigate to Stapi app directory and run it, and in another terminal window run your React App. You could right a script to run them both with one command but the method I'm suggesting should be easier

Comment: Is there other simple alternative frontend for strapi?

Comment: Strapi is a headless CMS, so it has a 'frontend' if you like already when you use the package. All Strapi does is manage your content (your BE) in a visually appealing manner; and your separate frontend app (React etc) will receive this data from the backend and display it with your desired format. Here are the [Strapi docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/getting-started/quick-start.html#_1-install-strapi-and-create-a-new-project)